# 18.04 gets stuck on aspire

Tags: acer, aspire

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 to my notebook (acer aspire E15 E5-511-P7AT). Before, I had lubuntu 16.04; the problem did not occur then. Now more and more often, but in irragular intervalls, the computer gets stuck and the screen freezes. No reaction to any input. After complete shutdown by turning off power and restart it works perfectly again - until the next freeze. A few seconds after the freeze, the fan (which normally is very low and can't be heard) powers up for some seconds. Has anyone an idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Can you try changing your `/etc/default/grub` by adding `pnpacpi=off` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT? Then run `sudo update-grub` And try to see if it improves the freezing behaviour.

Comment: I followed the suggestion (thanks!). Now it looks like the intervals are getting longer (which is not sure, because they were very differnt before), but the freezing still occurs. - Maybe its a hardware prolem ...

Comment: Can you run the following command and report the model of CPU? `sudo dmidecode -s processor-version`

Comment: Result is
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3530  @ 2.16GHz

Comment: Unfortunately that's the answer I was dreading, it's a Bay Trail processor that is known to have problems with Linux. The only way to fix the issue that I know of is to reduce massively the support of the C states of the CPU. 

You should be able to stop the hanging by replacing the `pnpacpi=off` that I suggested before by `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`. 

That might increase the overall temperature of your laptop and reduce the battery life.

I think there has been some improvement in Kernel 5.0 for Bay Trail so you might have some luck using Ubuntu 19.04 instead, but no guarantee.